# Insert an id attribute into the next <p> tag in a string in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a string in a variable called $body

```
$body = '<p>Text.</p>
        <div class="my-class">Text.</div>
        <p>Text.</p>
        <p>Text.</p>
        <p>Text.</p>';
```

I want to change it to

```
$body = '<p>Text.</p>
            <div class="my-class">Text.</div>
            <p id="p1">Text.</p>
            <p>Text.</p>
            <p>Text.</p>';
```

Assume there are an unknown number of `<p>Text.</p>` paragraphs before the `<div class="my-class">` and an unknown number of `<p>Text.</p>` paragraphs after. So I don't know the position of the `<div class="my-class">` in the string variable.

How do I do this in PHP?

Here's the best of what I've come up with.

Later in the script I converted the $body string into a $body array with explode()

```
$html_tags = [
  '</p>' => '</p>|',
  '</div>' => '</div>|',
  '\/>' => '\/>|',
];
foreach ($html_tags as $key => $value) {
  $body = str_replace($key, $value, $body);
}
$paragraphs = explode('|', $body);

// Remove trailing </p>.
array_pop($paragraphs);
```

I can do this because I know all the tags $body contains.

Now that $body is an array, I can add `' id="p1"'` to the p tag after `<div class="my-class">` with

```
foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($value, 'my-class') !== FALSE) {
    $next_paragraph = $array[$key - 1];
    $newText = ' id="p1"';
    $newstr = substr_replace($next_paragraph, $newText, 6, 0);
    dsm($newstr);
  }
}
```

But at that point I'm on an index looping through an array. One array index doesn't seem to be able to change the next array index.

But before it's an array it's a string. If I can alter the string, I'll be good to go.

Comment: PHP outputs HTML so changing it using PHP doesn't make much sense. Unless everything in your question is already being created and output by PHP. Regardless, please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry. Thought it would be easier if I just asked it as a question. Added more of my thinking/code to the question.

Comment: My answer is updated. No need to edit your question with "what worked" if it's largely similar to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how to work with HTML. It's a markup language and needs to be parsed as such. Use XPath to find the element you're looking for, and DomDocument to change it.

```
<?php
$body = '<p>Text.</p>
        <div class="my-class">Text.</div>
        <p>Text.</p>
        <p>Text.</p>
        <p>Text.</p>';

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML("<html>$body</html>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
// this looks complicated, but essentially things inside square brackets are conditions
// so we're looking for the first p with a preceding div that has a class of "my-class"
// note XPath is not zero-based, hence the [1] instead of [0]
$paras = $xpath->query("//p[preceding::div[@class='my-class']][1]");
// alter the element; the nodes are all references so $dom is also getting updated
// a list is always returned even with one element, so have to use array notation
$paras[0]->setAttribute("id", "p1");

// output the new HTML
$html = "";
foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $n) {
    $html .= $dom->saveHTML($n);
}
echo $html;
```

Output:

```
<p>Text.</p>
        <div class="my-class">Text.</div>
        <p id="p1">Text.</p>
        <p>Text.</p>
        <p>Text.</p>
```